# Computed styles acting strange on local file

Tags: html, css, computed-style

I'm having a problem with computed styles on my local file.

Please take a look at the image below.

On the left, my local file. On the right, the file on the server

[image]

If you notice, in firebug the font-size is striked-out because it gets overwritten somewhere else.
The thing is that it doesn't get overwritten anywhere else (you can also see that in firebug).

In the computed styles, you can see that the font-size is 16px when it should be 12.8px.

**Note:** I'm loading the .css files directly from the server even in my local file so they are using the same files.

Does anyone know why it's acting this way?

Thank you.

Comment: Are the CSS files being loaded in the same order on both servers?

Comment: Yes. It loads the same css files in the same order.